# MusicBrainz Picard: How to fill only certain tags, sort into least albums, and "disallow" multi-artist albums

Tags: music, id3, music-management

Here is what I want:

- Fill only: Genre, Date (As the original release), and Album
- Sort into the least amount of albums
- Don't use albums with multiple/various artists

The artist and title tags are already filled, so I really don't need audio fingerprints or anything like that - just fetch the info, sort, fill. My music collection is not as big as others, but it is a daunting task to do one by one.

If this question has been asked and answered, I'm sorry. My Google fu isn't very good :-p

*P.S.: I would prefer the date to be formatted like "m/d/yyyy" instead of "yyyy-mm-dd"*

Answer (score 0):

Picard should fill in missing tags, but I am not sure if you can [explicitly set which fields to save](http://forums.musicbrainz.org/viewtopic.php?id=4418).

I am currently using this file naming scheme:

> $if2(%grouping%,%genre%)/$if($eq(%albumartist%,Various Artists),%artist%,%albumartist%)/$if(%originaldate%,$left(%originaldate%,4)) $if($gt(%totaldiscs%,1),%discnumber%-,)$if($ne(%albumartist%,),$num(%tracknumber%,2) ,)%title%

To explain:

- the first path created looks at grouping tag. If it is empty, genre will be used.
- the second path will albumartist that is "Various Artists" and use artist instead. Otherwise, use albumartist
- Third path is original release date of song (year only) plus the default disc number, track number, and song title.

This thread may help for your [specific Picard date formatting](http://web.archive.org/web/20141109060813/http://forums.musicbrainz.org/viewtopic.php?id=4469).

Comment: Wow... I thought this question was long dead. Either way, Picard tried to auto fill by audio signatures. I think it calls it Music ID or something like that. I have versions that are not standard versions, so it drops them on an odd album such as  "Greatest Hits" and such. I don't like those albums and it's frustrating. Anyway, I probably won't need this anymore as I am re-downloading them with better tags, but it would be nice info for people to have.

Comment: @Timberwolf Did you ever solve this? I just want to update the Year field of my MP3s and leave all other fields untouched.

Comment: +1 for me. I want to update everything except the album.

Answer (score 0):

1. AFAIK there's no include-only list, but there's an exclude list here:

`Options > Clear Existing Tags: Disable`
`Options > Tags > Preserve these tags`

2. Ensure that you cluster album tracks by selecting all tracks in an album then choosing the cluster option in the main panel. Then use the lookup feature on the cluster (not the scan option).

Also set the following options:

`Options > Metadata > Preferred Releases > Preferred release types`: increase Album; decrease ones you don't want
`Options > Advanced > Matching > Thresholds`: decrease cluster; increase file

3. Set the following option:

`Options > Metadata > Preferred Releases > Preferred release types`: set Compilation to zero

4. You'll likely need to find/write a script to reformat the date fields, then go to:

`Options > Scripting > Enable Tagger Scripts`
`Options > Scripting > Add New Tagger Script`: rename it in the left pane, paste the code in the right pane